# mongod.lock file permissions on shared system

Tags: macos, mongodb, permissions

I am working on a shared mac OS X 10.6 system, and am having trouble setting up an instance of MongoDB. I do not have any way of attaining root privileges.

I have set a separate --dbpath from the standard /data/db directory.

When I run mongod with my custom configuration file, I get the common 10310 error:

```
2015-06-02T12:18:53.110-0700 kern.sched unavailable
2015-06-02T12:18:53.115-0700 [initandlisten] MongoDB starting :    pid=88680 port=27017 dbpath=/mir/ew/ntellis/mongodata 64-bit   host=fornax.astro.berkeley.edu
2015-06-02T12:18:53.115-0700 [initandlisten] 
2015-06-02T12:18:53.115-0700 [initandlisten] ** WARNING: soft rlimits too low. Number of files is 256, should be at least 1000
2015-06-02T12:18:53.115-0700 [initandlisten] db version v2.6.10
2015-06-02T12:18:53.115-0700 [initandlisten] git version: 5901dbfb49d16eaef6f2c2c50fba534d23ac7f6c
2015-06-02T12:18:53.115-0700 [initandlisten] build info: Darwin bs- osx-108-x86-64-2.10gen.cc 12.3.0 Darwin Kernel Version 12.3.0: Sun Jan  6 22:37:10 PST 2013; root:xnu-2050.22.13~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64 BOOST_LIB_VERSION=1_49
2015-06-02T12:18:53.115-0700 [initandlisten] allocator: system
2015-06-02T12:18:53.116-0700 [initandlisten] options: { storage: { dbPath: "/mir/ew/ntellis/mongodata" } }
2015-06-02T12:18:53.176-0700 [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: 10310 Unable to lock file: /mir/ew/ntellis/mongodata/mongod.lock. Is a mongod instance already running?, terminating
2015-06-02T12:18:53.176-0700 [initandlisten] dbexit: 
2015-06-02T12:18:53.176-0700 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
2015-06-02T12:18:53.176-0700 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to flush diaglog...
2015-06-02T12:18:53.176-0700 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close sockets...
2015-06-02T12:18:53.176-0700 [initandlisten] shutdown: waiting for fs preallocator...
2015-06-02T12:18:53.176-0700 [initandlisten] shutdown: lock for final commit...
2015-06-02T12:18:53.176-0700 [initandlisten] shutdown: final commit...
2015-06-02T12:18:53.176-0700 [initandlisten] shutdown: closing all files...
2015-06-02T12:18:53.176-0700 [initandlisten] closeAllFiles() finished
2015-06-02T12:18:53.176-0700 [initandlisten] dbexit: really exiting now
```

I have tried deleting the lock file, changing directory permissions, removing the data directory entirely, and a few other tricks. The mongod  process appears to be successfully creating the lock file on launch, then failing to lock it a fraction of a second later.

Could this be a problem with permissions assigned to the process on launch? Is this a problem I will need to go to my server admin with?

Thank you for the help.

Comment: Did you check if there is already a mongod process running? If so kill it and then start mongod again.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! There is no mongod process running. I can manually delete the .pid file and the same error comes up.